# jQuery to animate image from left to right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a Bee image and I want to animate it using jQuery.

The idea is to move the image from left (outside of screen) to right (outside of screen) to create an effect like it's flying.

Comment: Unfortunately jQuery does not work on bee's, birds only. Take at look at the jQuery site, there's a pretty decent documentation on the animate function, and how to do exactly this kind of thing, with birds that is !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your bee needs to be absolutely positioned, something like this:

```
<div id="b" style="position:absolute; top:50px">B</div>
```

I've used a div here, but it could just as well be an `<img>` tag. As meo pointed out, don't forget the `top` attribute, because some browsers don't work without it.  Then you can animate it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b").animate({left: "+=500"}, 2000);
    $("#b").animate({left: "-=300"}, 1000);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DonamiteIsTNT/KaTNH/) is a jsfiddle demo.

If you want to have a continuous animation as Hira pointed out, put the animation code in functions, make sure the left and right movement is the same, and use the onComplete option of animate() to call the next animation:

```
function beeLeft() {
    $("#b").animate({left: "-=500"}, 2000, "swing", beeRight);
}
function beeRight() {
    $("#b").animate({left: "+=500"}, 2000, "swing", beeLeft);
}

beeRight();
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DonamiteIsTNT/KaTNH/5/) for that.

Comment: dont forget to provide a top position to avoid unexpected behavior in browsers i do not mention :)

Comment: but it will animate just one time no continuous motion.

Comment: @meo, right you are, very good point.  I was just trying to get away with the least amount of work.  I expect the bee will be positioned top as well as a few other things (background, if spriting, etc).

Comment: @Hira, that's correct.  I wasn't assuming Andrei wanted continuous animation.  But that's easy enough: just stick the animation code in a setInterval and then make sure the + and - values are the same.  I'll update it to include both points.

Comment: + you could pack call the bee function in the callback of your seconde animation, so you are sure the animation is finished... Timing in JS is not so precise...

Answer (score 7):

Try spritely: http://spritely.net/

Answer (score 4):

i would do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Uwuwj/2/

```
var b = function($b,speed){
var beeWidth = $b.width();

$b.animate({ //animates the bee to the right side of the screen
    "left": "100%"
}, speed, function(){ //when finished it goes back to the left side
    $b.animate({
        "left": 0 - beeWidth + "px"
    }, speed, function(){
        b($b, speed) //finally it recalls the same function and everything starts again
    });
});
};

$(function(){ //document ready
    b($("#b"), 5000); //calls the function
});
```

bee careful, this code only works with bee's :P

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the bee to keep flying across the screen, try this :-)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function animateImage() {
            console.log("Called");
            $('#bee').css({right:'10%'});   
            $('#bee').animate({right: '-100%'}, 5000, 'linear', function(){animateImage();});
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            animateImage();             
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 100%;"><img src="bee.jpg" id="bee" style="position:relative;"/></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          function rgt() {
              $('#sldr').animate({ left: "500" }, 10000, hider);
            }
            rgt();
            function hider() {
            $('#sldr').css('left', '0px');
                rgt();
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
         <img id="sldr" src="../Images/animated%20images/birds/rightfuglan.gif" style="position:absolute" />
      </div>
    </form>
</body
```

>

Comment: this code for moving a image from left to right continuously without any distortion

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var k = $(window).width();

            function rgt() {
                $('#sldl').hide(1);
                $('#sldr').animate({ left: "1000" }, 10000, hider);
            }
            rgt();

            function hider() {
                $('#sldr').css('left', '0px');
                $('#sldr').hide(1);
                $('#sldl').show();
                lft();
            }

            function lft() {
                $('#sldl').animate({ left: "0" }, 10000, hidel);
            }

            function hidel() {
                $('#sldl').css('left', '1000px');
                $('#sldr').show();
                rgt();
            }


        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
        <img id="sldl" src="../Images/animated%20images/birds/fuglan.gif" style="position:absolute; right:0px" />
         <img id="sldr" src="../Images/animated%20images/birds/rightfuglan.gif" style="position:absolute" />
      </div>
    </form>
</body>`enter code here`
```

Comment: this one for two images moves from left to right and right to left not at a time .when image in left side(1st image) moves to right after it again come back to starting position and 1st image will hide.and now image in right side (2nd image) ti now its hidden will made to show and starts moving towards left and and hide after it reaches the left position and again it came back to starting position and the process repeat
)thats not showing till the 1st image hiding