# jQuery to animate images: left and right with a flip/rotation effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to adapt this really simple and effective jQuery script:
[jQuery to animate image from left to right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957962/jquery-to-animate-image-from-left-to-right) (thanks DonamiteIsTnt)...

I would like to know how to expand upon it so you could effectively use two images with a "switch" animation. For example, a bird flies to the right of the screen - flip animation - bird appears to fly back to the left - flip animation - flies to the right again.

The "switch" animation I was thinking something along the lines of a 2D image effectively turning upon itself (like a goldfish swimming back and forth in a bowl and how it would appear to us from the front of the glass).

I don't know if you would use a single image in this case and shrink it from 30px wide to 0px then -30px, etc. to face it the other way. Or need to switch between a right-facing image and a left-facing image. Either way, it would be cool to have it animated.

I have found similar questions on this site referring to the left and right effect and the flip effect, but not combined. So any help would be greatly appreciated!

As a side note: I have linked to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

Edit: Have got this far...

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

function beeRight() {
    $("#b").animate({left: "+=300"}, 5000, "swing", beeLeft);
    $("#img").attr("src","rightArrow.gif");
}
function beeLeft() {
    $("#b").animate({left: "-=300"}, 5000, "swing", beeRight);
    $("#img").attr("src","leftArrow.gif");
}
beeRight();
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
<div id="b" style="position:absolute;"><img id="img" src="rightArrow.gif"></div>
    </body>
```

How would I then add an animated image swap such as: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php - needless to say, does not need to be as complicated. I'm looking to do this with img's, not div's. I understand how something like this would be done in CSS but I do not know how to incorporate it with the jQuery/Javascript.

Thanks again!

Comment: changing the image depends on the elements you use. When you use `<img>`, then you need to change the `scr`-attribute before chinging the animation direction. If you use another element then you use probably a background-image, what needs to be changed.

Comment: Most likely an <img> - it makes more sense as I'm likely to have it overlay a static background in most applications. I feel it may be easier then to also have more than one animation (such as a bird and a bee flying independently) in one place by using CSS positioning and z-index...? Which do you think would be more flexible?

Comment: An `<img>` is perfectly ok. Just use something like `$("#img").attr("src","flyleft.jpg");` before you change the direction of the animation.

Comment: And that is all you have asked for. Or? You change the image source before every direction change of the animation, that's it.

Comment: Edited my post with the code and hopefully you'll be able to help me with the next step... ^^;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the browsers you're targeting, you could achieve the effect entirely in CSS3. Use a couple of classes to represent the beginning and ending states and some [`translatex transforms`](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/02/moving-web-page-elements-using-the-css3-translate-transform/) and [`scalex transforms`](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp) to handle the flipping. Then add CSS `transition` property to animate. Then you can use whatever you like to trigger the class change, `:hover`, jQuery timer, element click, whatever.

Comment: Thank you very much for those links! They are just what I was looking for to help me get started on this project!
I'm assuming you would need to still use jQuery however to have it all function autonomously? Ie. if I was to create, in CSS, a left transition, right-flip, right transition, left flip, repeat, etc; jQuery would still be needed tell the browser to run those functions without a hover/click prompt (on page load) and repeat indefinitely?
In the same fashion as the code above?

Comment: Nevermind my previous question, from your post and continuing my research, I've found CSS3 animation and @keyframes. They do everything I want to and more! Here I was thinking JS and jQuery were the only answers to automated things on a website; shows how narrow-minded I have been toward the power of CSS! Thank you jxpx777 for leading me in the right direction! I found this website is a good explanation of CSS animation: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations) - the only downside, works in every browser bar I.E. Anyone know a work around?