# How to move image slowly with animation when appending the image to <td> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to find a way to move image from one cell to other cell using animation.
I know how to do it using the `animate()` function according to:
[jQuery to animate image from left to right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957962/jquery-to-animate-image-from-left-to-right)

I want to find to a way to do it when I am **appending** image to a new cell.
[image]

You here the DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/305eyytw/1/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<table oncontextmenu="return false">
<tr>
<td cellnumber="21" row="4" col="0"><span>21</span>
<img src="http://s4.postimg.org/58a4av7a5/player_1.png" cellnumber="21" class="soldiers" playernumber="1" soldiernumber="1" onclick="onMouseClickSoldier(this)" style="top: 0px; left: 0px;"/>
</td>

<td cellnumber="22" row="4" col="1"><span>22</span></td>

<td id="td3" cellnumber="23" row="4" col="2"><span>23</span></td>  
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
td {
    width: 90px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
table
{
    position: fixed;
    left:9px;
    top:8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd), tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even)
{
    background:#00A2E8;
}

.soldiers
{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position: absolute;
}

td span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function onMouseClickSoldier(soldier)
{
    //alert(3);
    var newCell = $("#td3"); 
    //$(soldier).appendTo(newCell);
    $(soldier).animateAppendTo(newCell, 1000);
}


$.fn.animateAppendTo = function(sel, speed) {
    var $this = this,
        newEle = $this.clone(true).appendTo(sel),
        newPos = newEle.position();
    newEle.hide();
    $this.css('position', 'absolute').animate(newPos, speed, function() {
        newEle.show();
        $this.remove();
    });
    return newEle;
};
```

Comment: Problem was in the creation of your fiddle. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/305eyytw/1/)

Comment: thanks, I edited my question with the correct fiddle. I still searching for a way to creaet animation when append image to new cell

Comment: for slow u can change  $(soldier).animateAppendTo(newCell, 1000); into  $(soldier).animateAppendTo(newCell, 2000); so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `.position()` and perhaps your logic because `newEle.position()` always returns `{top: 0, left: 0}` ofcourse because you haven't changed it. Use this replacement of the function and it should work:

```
$.fn.animateAppendTo = function (sel, speed) {
    var $this = this,
        newEle = $this.clone(true).appendTo(sel),
        newPos = newEle.position();
    newEle.hide();
    $this.animate({
        left: "+=" + 192
    }, speed);
    return newEle;
};
```

What I have done is that I saw the width of one td and multiplied it by 2 and added an assumed width of the image, 12, to the answer to obtain the approximate position of the soldier and fixed your problem in the `.animate()`'s first parameter which takes in an object and made the soldier animate to left with an increment of 192 pixels over 1000ms as you gave the time. Hope that works.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/305eyytw/2/)

**UPDATE:**
Anyways, here is a solution that works without any calculations:

```
$.fn.animateAppendTo = function (sel, speed) {
    var $this = this,
        newEle = $this.clone(true).appendTo(sel),
        newPos = newEle.position();
    newEle.hide();
    $this.animate({
        left: "+=" + $("#td3").position().left
    }, speed);
    return newEle;
};
```

The magic here is to use `$("#td3").position().left` which pretty much gives us the `x-axis` position of the td3 where you want the soldier to be.

Comment: I familiar with this. I wanted to avoid from this calculations because this is part of game I am creating and it more comfortable  to use appendTo() function but make it slowly with the use of "+="

Comment: @EviatarG. Calculations are part of the game(not the one you are creating instead a pun was intended), either store it in a variable or comment it out in your code how did that came in