# Animated effect in multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my scenario,

I am having 4 images on top of my webpage, named img1,img2,img3,img4.

Now I am also having 4 images on my bottom my webpage named fly1,fly2,fly3,fly4

Now, I have a button in my screen named, 'Done'. When I click it, Images shown on bottom should fly and fix over the images shown on top, as shown order below,

```
fly1 fly and fix over img3
fly2 fly and fix over img1
fly3 fly and fix over img4
fly4 fly and fix over img2
```

For your better understanding I ve placed my code in jsffiddle, please make a note of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/premkumar_ks16/a09bshb7/29/

I can't achieve, Anyhow I tried

Please guide me

Regards,
Arun

Comment: you can atlest put some valid images there..

Comment: Thank you Anoop for your response. I've updated please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/premkumar_ks16/a09bshb7/29/) link you shared, the only change required in your code is adding a `position: absolute` property to the css of the flying image

```
$("#fly1").css({
    "top": v.top + "px",
    "left": v.left + "px",
    "position": "absolute",
});
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shikhar/a09bshb7/31/).

Without absolute position, html elements have a default `static` position value, because of which the elements render in order as appeared in the document flow

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a better start

http://jsfiddle.net/KaTNH/1589/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b").animate({top: "+=500"}, 2000);
    $("#b").animate({top: "-=300"}, 1000);
});
```

[jQuery to animate image from left to right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957962/jquery-to-animate-image-from-left-to-right)